# format a string using regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I need some help, I have this kind of adresses in a csv file and I need a regex to format in a different way, I tried but I'm not practical of regex and it's easy to confuse me when talking about this argument

that's the original address

**10, Via della Libertà - 90100 Palermo (PA)**

and I need it in this way

**Via della Libertà, 10, 90100 Palermo (PA)**

what can I do? I have to do it in php

Comment: Post what did you try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$str` is your csv content

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+),\s([^\-]+)\-/', function($matches){
    return trim($matches[2]).', '.$matches[1].', ';
}, $str);
```

Comment: Just to help him understand what's written:
he extracts the street's number as a group and the street's name as another group (the - char is removed cause it does match the researched string, BUT it is not inserted in the second group). (\d+) means "create a grounp () by finding a sequence of numbers \d  with 1 or more repetitions +; then ther's the coma , used as separator and a whitespace \s. He creates another group by selecting at least one char which does not contain ^ a - (escaped by a \)

Comment: It's not a rocket science. Regular expressions are documented here http://php.net/pcre

Comment: Probably I was wrong trying to help someone who wrote "I tried but I'm not practical of regex and it's easy to confuse me". Sometimes explaing something can make someone able to do it by himself/herself the next time (and regular expressions are not well known for their readability).

Comment: i'm studying regex, and i wrote the first part (\d+), but i stucked in the second part because i still can't understand why there is no indicator of what to look for (like [a-z] or something like this including symbols)

anyway, thank you so much for the help!